# Storing part of regex using javascript match

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I want to find all `#tags` in a piece of text (using javascript) and use them. The regex `myString.match(/#\w+/g)` works, but then I also get the #. How can I get only the word without the #?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var code='...';
var patt=/#(\w+)/g;
var result=patt.exec(code);

while (result != null) {
    alert(result[1]);
    result = patt.exec(code);    
}
```

The `(` and `)` denote groups. You can then access these groups and see what they contain. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) and [here](http://www.daaq.net/old/javascript/index.php?page=regexp%20grouping&parent=js%20regexp) for additional information.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I was a bit disappointed that you can't do this with the match function..

Comment: @Niels Glad it worked. If this solved your problem please mark the green 'very good' sign on the left ;)

Comment: yes I'm waiting for the stupid 4 minutes i have to wait before I can accept your answer. What is this delay for...

Comment: @Niels Maybe it allows other people to submit their answers which might be better than the ones already provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = myString.match(/#\w+/g);
result.forEach(function (word, index, arr){
    arr[index] = word.slice(1);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gDghQ/)

Note that I'm using ES5's `forEach` here. You can easily replace it with a for loop, so it looks  like this:

```
var result = myString.match(/#\w+/g);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    result[i] = result[i].slice(1);
}
```

[Demo without forEach](http://jsfiddle.net/gDghQ/1/)

[Docs on forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)